# How to wrap outer div element according its child width?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Card</title>
   <style>
     .container {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       background-color: rgb(185, 133, 65);
       border: 2px solid red;
     }
     .left {
       background-color: brown;
     }
     .right {
       background-color: darkcyan;
     }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Output:
[image: output of the code]

But i don't want the extra space after the div "saiful" here. I also want to use the feature of display:flex here. How can i do that?

Comment: which of the classes do you want to take up the remaining space or do you want the container class to only be as wide as the two elements?

Comment: This is what your output is right now: https://nimb.ws/WIeqmM

Comment: @m4n0 I have fixed the code.

Comment: @UdenduAbasili I wanted the container class to only be as wide as the two element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `display: inline-flex;` instead of `display: flex;` can solve the issue.

```
.container {
       display: inline-flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       background-color: rgb(185, 133, 65);
       border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Now output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Card</title>
   <style>
     .container {
       display: inline-block;
       flex-direction: column;
       background-color: rgb(185, 133, 65);
       border: 2px solid red;
     }
     .left {
       background-color: brown;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left;
     }
     .right {
       background-color: darkcyan;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left; 
       clear:both;
   
     }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

1. `**display:inline-block;**` so it breaks the default div behaviour of spreading out on rest of space.
2. Break default float flow on child divs by adding **`float:left;`** then on second child add additional `**clear:both;**` to break its flow from previous item.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Card</title>
   <style>
     .container {
       display: inline-block;
       flex-direction: column;
       background-color: rgb(185, 133, 65);
       border: 2px solid red;
     }
     .left {
       background-color: brown;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left;
     }
     .right {
       background-color: darkcyan;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left;
   
     }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

1. In case you need them aligned next to each other simply remove `clear:both;` from second child.

UPDATED EXAMPLE with more than one container;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Card</title>
   <style>
    .navwarper {
       display: inline-block;
       flex-direction: column;
       border: none;
     }
     .container {
       display: inline-block;
       flex-direction: column;
       background-color: rgb(185, 133, 65);
       border: 2px solid red;
        float:left;
     }
     .left {
       background-color: brown;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left;
     }
     .right {
       background-color: darkcyan;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left; 
      
   
     }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="navwarper">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

You create a warper div within which container divs are added as child to which you have its own child.  technically speaking warper div is grand parent to left and right divs. Again trick is to give float left rule on container div so they align next to each other rather than breaking line.

ANOTHER EXAMPLE (Just in case)
have updated original answer in below example there is no grandparent just parent child relationship and you can have as many child's as you want they would align next to each other.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Card</title>
   <style>
    .navwarper {
       display: inline-block;
       flex-direction: column;
       border: none;
     }
     .container {
       display: inline-block;
       flex-direction: column;
       background-color: rgb(185, 133, 65);
       border: 2px solid red;
     
     }
     .left {
       background-color: brown;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left;
     }
     .right {
       background-color: darkcyan;
       display:inline-block;
       float:left; 
      
   
     }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  
   <div class="container">
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>

     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>

     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
  
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>
  
     <div class="left">Name</div>
     <div class="right">Saiful</div>

   </div>
 </body>
```

PS: it was weirdly breaking on mobile view because because there was typo mistake in code i.e. class container was mis spelled as continer or something like that so it was not in full effect. plus you need media query to fully adjust to view port.

Comment: This code breaks the feature. Div "Name" and "Saiful" is showing in two different line. But it should be one after another on same line.

Comment: @Saiful Islam Niloy have updated answer with second example

Comment: in your updated answer, it works fine for a single card. But if i have multiple card then it breaks weirdly in mobile view. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f6wSWn7s-ggmYr3-ki9KX3Rl9v7m-ndg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want it like this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G5c3E38mBM1nM1zvLNNYx3qSsf9w6bRx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have updated answer with an updated example :)

Comment: your updated code breaks again in mobile view. The outer div background has been shown.
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lSKpTdZxIgCkZzNEqpbxgh0YzJuJRO8k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: code is doing precisely what it is suppose to do. it will not spread the divs nor shrink them to keep everything on same line. It will manage what it can then what ever does not fit in will break and  go to next line. This default and designed behaviour of css, thats why I had said you need media query, to decide what to show and what to hide on  mobile view and desktop view and how to show it.

Comment: have look at this example it is using media queries to show things on different view ports. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav here is another https://medialoot.com/preview/css-only-navigation-menu/index.html . for sanity sake ..... do not expect one code to work its way into all view ports....if your question now demands media queries might as well open new question thread.

Comment: I believe your original question How to wrap outer div element according its child width? and query But i don't want the extra space after the div "saiful" here. I also want to use the feature of display:flex here. How can i do that? has been answered and thread should be closed.... mobile view seems to be an after thought and should be opened as new thread. Because its a different code work altogether

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
       display: flex;
       width: fit-content;
       flex-direction: row;
       background-color: rgb(185, 133, 65);
       border: 2px solid red;
     }
```

Use `width: fit-content`

Comment: Yes, fit-content can fix it for one card. But suppose, you have multiple card like this. Then, it appears in separate row.  https://codepen.io/saiful-islam-niloy/pen/GRrzyZZ

Comment: If you want to solve this problem with another div.big-container css using flex, it breaks in mobile view. https://codepen.io/saiful-islam-niloy/pen/vYgbpKO